# $A, B$ be two subsets of a metric space such that $\bar A \cap \bar B = \emptyset$, then prove that $\partial(A\cup B)=\partial A \cup \partial B$

Tags: metric-spaces

To prove the above-mentioned statement, I am just able to show $\partial(A\cup B)\subseteq \partial A \cup \partial B$ in the following manner
$\partial A \cup \partial B=$
$(\bar A \backslash A^\circ)\cup (\bar B \backslash B^\circ)=(\bar A \cup \bar B)\backslash (A^\circ \cup B^\circ)=(\overline {A \cup B})\backslash (A^\circ \cup B^\circ)\supseteq (\overline {A \cup B})\backslash (A \cup B)^\circ= \partial (A\cup B)$
$\implies \partial (A \cup B)  \subseteq \partial A \cup \partial B \tag {1}\label{eq1}$
But it is general implication, I've not used the fact $\bar A \cap \bar B = \emptyset$ to prove $\eqref{eq1}$.
How to prove that $\partial A \cup \partial B \subseteq \partial(A\cup B) $?
Can anybody help me find the wayout? Thank for the assisatance in advance.
**N.B**. Here $\bar A = A \cup A^d$, where $A^d$ denotes the set of all limit points of $A$; $A^\circ$ denotes the set of all interior points of $A$; $\partial A$ denotes the set of all boundary points of A i.e. set of those points which are not interior nor exterior points of $A$.

Comment: You just edited all your inclusions to go the other way. I don't think that that was right. Considering $A = (0,1)$ and $B = (1, 2)$ in $\Bbb R$, the "easy" and generally true conclusion is that $\partial(A\cup B)\subseteq \partial A\cup \partial B$ (which in my example here would be $\{0, 2\}\subseteq \{0,1,2\}$), while the one where you need $\bar A\cap\bar B=\varnothing$ is $\partial A\cup\partial B\subseteq \partial(A\cup B)$.

Answer (score 2):

> I've not used the fact $\bar A \cap \bar B = \emptyset$ to prove $\eqref{eq1}$. How to prove that $\partial A \cup \partial B \subseteq \partial(A\cup B)$?

Well, you're kindof answering your own question there. The fact $\bar A \cap \bar B = \emptyset$ is exactly what makes the $\supseteq$ in $\overline{(A\cup B)}\setminus(A^\circ \cup B^\circ)\supseteq (\overline {A \cup B})\setminus(A \cup B)^\circ$ into $=$ because it implies
$$A^\circ \cup B^\circ=(A \cup B)^\circ$$

Comment: you are saying that $\bar A \cap \bar B=\emptyset$ implies $(A\cup B)^\circ = A^\circ \cup B^\circ$. Am I right?

Comment: @BiswarupSaha That is what I'm saying, yes.